# ORDER BY before SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm just trying to add in an the newest estimated return date for a car as part of a subquery in my Select statement, I just wanted to know if this was how it is done?

I think I heard that Select happens before Order By so wanted to do a quick check.

```sql
select top 1 ESTIMATE_RETURN_DATE 
from CHECK.AOS 
where AOS.AUTO_NO = CHECK_EVENT.AUTONUM_4 
ORDER BY REVISION_NO desc
```

Comment: What happened when you tested the query?

Comment: It runs fine and I am getting the right estimated return date, but my sample size is 4 so I just want to make sure that top 1 happens after the ordering

Comment: top 1 happens after the ordering

Comment: great that's all I needed to know thank you!

Comment: Using max() might be more efficient than top 1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ORDER BY is evaluated **before** the SELECT, as the ordering changes the results returned.

`TOP 1` also ensures the lowest `REVISION_NO` is returned, therefore it appears you are using the query correctly.

Comment: The SELECT happens before the ORDER BY clause, and top clause hapens after the ORDER BY

Answer (score 1):

I was pretty sure, but this explains it http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/top-n-queries

It selects everything and sorts then stops when it reaches the number to return.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Top works after OrderBY. First it will find all the records and then it would apply Top. So you are doing it right. I am also writing down the order in which a query process in sql server

```
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
SELECT
ORDER BY
TOP/OFFSET FETCH
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have will work.  I think of it like this:

"SQL" needs to get the data before it can sort (order) the data.

This is a great resource:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/

I am not affiliated with that website at all, or any of the people who contribute to it, jsut have found it helpful in the past (and continue to find it helpful!).